# Enabling Audio Transmission from GCP Cloud VM using Remote Access App

Tags: google-cloud-platform, audio, cloud, virtual-machine, instance

I have set up a Google Cloud Platform (GCP) virtual machine (VM) running Ubuntu Server. As expected, the VM doesn't have any audio hardware installed. Currently, I'm using Google's remote desktop app to access the VM, but I can switch to any other compatible app if needed. However, audio transmission is not functional through the remote access app. How can I enable audio transmission from the GCP Cloud VM to my local machine despite the absence of audio hardware? Additionally, I'm curious to know if there are specific operating systems that inherently support this functionality. Any insights or solutions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

I haven't tried anything.